# JButton setText() ERROR

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to set a new text into a button when you press on it. However it does not seem to work, I am doing something wrong, and I do not know what...

EDIT -----I attach the code for easier comprehension of what I mean

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GrowAndShrinkSquareGUItest {
JFrame frame;
SquareDrawPanel bigGreen;
SquareDrawPanel smallGreen;
JButton button;
growAndShrinkListener listener;

public class SquareDrawPanel extends JPanel {

    int width;
    int height;

    SquareDrawPanel(int w, int h) {

        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(frame.getWidth() / 2 - (width / 2), frame.getHeight()
                / 2 - (height / 2) - 15, width, height);

    }

}

public class growAndShrinkListener implements ActionListener {

    // JButton button;

    growAndShrinkListener(JButton button) {

        button = new JButton("Click me to grow the Square");
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        button.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        button.setText("Unselect all");

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GrowAndShrinkSquareGUItest test = new GrowAndShrinkSquareGUItest();
    test.go();
}

private void createPanels() {

    bigGreen = new SquareDrawPanel(400, 400);
    smallGreen = new SquareDrawPanel(100, 100);

}

private void drawPanel(JPanel panel) {

    frame.add(panel);
    panel.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}

private void createListenerButton() {
    listener = new growAndShrinkListener(button);
}

private void loop(){}

public void go() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    createPanels();
    drawPanel(smallGreen);
    createListenerButton();
    frame.setVisible(true);


}
```

}

Comment: Please specify the error.

Comment: Where is `button` defined? It doesn't seem to be defined for the `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: This class is a inner class of a bigger one. I declared button in the superclass.

Comment: This is like asking I would like you to help my find my item, it is green please find it. Please specify what the output is and what you are expecting.

Comment: The problem is this line `button = new JButton("Click me to grow the Square");`. You're overwriting the value of the constructor argument `button`. This doesn't affect the instance variable `button`. A sime change to `this.button = new JButton("Click me to grow the Square");` may not work, so see the answers for a better code structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you use the `button` variable that is not defined in the scope of `actionPerformed` method. Java variables have scope and they are available inside curly braces where they're defined. The `actionPerformed` method is out of the curly braces of `growAndShrinkListener` method. The fixed code:

```
public class growAndShrinkListener implements ActionListener {



    growAndShrinkListener(JButton button) {

        button = new JButton("Click me to grow the Square");
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        button.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();

        if(source instanceof JButton) {
            button = (JButton) source;
            button.setText("Click to shrink square");
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a private variable:

```
public class growAndShrinkListener implements ActionListener {

    private JButton button;

    growAndShrinkListener() {

        button = new JButton("Click me to grow the Square");
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        button.addActionListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        button.setText("Click to shrink square");
    }
}
```

Note: You should not overwrite the content of the argument in the constructor. The argument that you got is not a "pointer" to the callee's variable, but just a simple reference to that. If you overwrite, then the content will be lost for you and calle will not know that.

Answer (score 0):

change like this..

```
public class YourSuperClass{
    private JButton button;
    public YourSuperClass(){
         // your logics 
         button = new JButton();
         button.addActionListener(new GrowAndShrinkListener(button));
         frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
    class GrowAndShrinkListener implements ActionListener {
        GrowAndShrinkListener(JButton button) {

        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == button){
                button.setText("Click to shrink square");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
        import javax.swing.*;
        import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.event.*;
        class frame extends JFrame 
       { 
       JButton b;
       public frame()
        {
           setLayout(new BorderLayout());
           b=new JButton("Press");
           add(b,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
           b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
             b.setText("Clicked");
            }
          });
        }

        public static void main (String[] args) {
            frame f=new frame();
            f.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
      }
```